# What type of highcharts to use for column charts with distribution within the column?

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I need to display a stacked column chart using Highcharts where each column denotes some overall percentage and within the column, there is a distribution which itself sums up to 100%. For eg:

Category1 : 45% (Sub-category values: [25%, 30%, 45%])
Category2 : 20% (Sub-category values: [15%, 50%, 35%])
Category3 : 35% (Sub-category values: [45%, 30%, 25%])

Comment: I think you need `chart: { type: 'column' }` with `plotOptions: { column: { stacking: 'normal' } }`. See [here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/)

Comment: That is my problem.. the example that you gave has the inner values of column adding upto total column value.. but the example that i gave doesnt follow that rule..

Comment: you have to have the sub values add up to the total in order to plot the values.  But you can use the formatter functions for the tooltip and/or data labels to then show the sub value percentages to the viewer.  So, calculate what 25, 30, and 45 % of 45 is, plot those values, and do the math to show the math to show the % to the viewer.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fod6dmep/